# Bad Sql Grammar Exception in spring JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE customer SET phone=?, email=? WHERE username=?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 3
```

This is a controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/editdetail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView editdetails(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, UserBean userBean,BindingResult result)
    {
        retrieveService.updates(userBean);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/welcomes");

    }
```

This is a DAO implementation code

```
public String updates(UserBean userBean) 
    {
        String sql="UPDATE customer SET phone=?, email=? WHERE username=?";  
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, userBean.getphone(), userBean.getemail());
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: You have not provided a parameter for `username=?` in `jdbcTemplate.update(sql, userBean.getphone(), userBean.getemail());`. It should be `jdbcTemplate.update(sql, userBean.getphone(), userBean.getemail(), userBean.getUsername());` or similar, depends on your `UserBean`

Comment: Yeah Its works but it would not update records

Comment: Well, that might be a different problem... This question is answered, so please ask another one containing your database tables and java code involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass username param value.

```
    String sql="UPDATE customer SET phone=?, email=? WHERE username=?";  
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, userBean.getphone(), userBean.getemail(), <someUserNameHere>);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are not providing any value for the 'username' parameter when you invoke the jdbcTemplates's update operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
//in DAO class
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
@autowired
@Qualifier(value="datasourceName")
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)
{
  this.jdbcTemplate=new JdbcTemplate(dataSource)
}
public String updates(UserBean userBean) 
{
         String phone =userBean.getphone();
         String email=userBean.getemail();
         String username=userBean.getusername()
         Object[] params = { phone,email,username};
         int[] types = {Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR};
         private static final String sql = "UPDATE customer SET  phone=?, email=? WHERE username=?";
        int rows=jdbcTemplate.update(sql, params,types);
        return null;
 }
```